# Why is my CNN model being trained in less time on my local CPU than hosted options?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-platform

I'm completely new to deep-learning and I've been following a few tutorials that have been mostly using hosted Jupyter notebooks (Azure and Colaboratory). I'm at a stage where I'm looking to start experimenting on my own neural networks; however, I'm a little confused by where I should be training my keras models. To decide, I ran the following model in a few different places and in summary my i5 6500 CPU came 2nd, which I found incredibly confusing. More confusing is that running Google Cloud Compute with 8 virtual CPUs was slower than running on my CPU. I have yet to try on my GTX1060 GPU; however, it seems reasonable to assume that it will perform even better than my CPU. **Why am I getting these results and where do people usually train their ML models? My results are below.**

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, array_to_img
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

image_height, image_width = 28, 28
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, image_height * image_width)
x_test = x_test.reshape(10000, image_height * image_width)

x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')

x_train /= 255.0
x_test /= 255.0

y_train = to_categorical(y_train, 10)
y_test = to_categorical(y_test, 10)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(784,)))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=2, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

I tried the above snippet in the following locations. Below are the per epoch times.

- My i5 6500 CPU: **20s**
- Colaboratory Notebook with CPU: **27s**
- Colaboratory Notebook with GPU: **8s** (expected)
- Colaboratory Notebook with TPU: **26s**
- Azure Notebook with CPU: **60s**
- Google Cloud Compute Jupyterlab: 4vCPUs: **36s**

[image]
[image]

- Google Cloud Compute Jupyterlab: 8vCPUs: **40s**

[image]
[image]

Unfortunately, running Google Cloud Compute with GPU requires me to upgrade my free account so I didn't get to try that.

Comment: You have to change your code to use TPUs (https://medium.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-on-tpus-on-colab-674367932aa0). In terms of CPU training, your local machine probably has 8 vCPUs. So I expect it to be faster than the 4vCPU cloud instances. The 8 vCPU cloud instance shouldn't be slower than the 4vCPU cloud instance; unless you are running into memory pressure (7.2 GB ram vs 15 GB ram). Make sure that you are testing with in memory data; otherwise there is IO to consider.

Comment: I suspect that locally, you have instant and direct access to when you run things. Meanwhile, using Google and other cloud platforms will take a few more sections to set up and allocate resources to their machines to run your models. The margin between your results are under a minute apart. I suspect you may not find much of a speed up until you start getting into really large datasets so that you can more utilize the cloud platforms.